# NSTImer Value calculation

Tags: ios

I am Developing an ios app for audio  player.

Here now i have to move one slider that represents the current playing track of the song

For Example my song duration is 6sec now i have to move the slider from x point =0 to x=480 by the time audio playing should Finnish it paying one loop.
I am moving the based up Nstimer. now i required the nstime interval for nstimer to move the slider correctly to end that is x=480.

myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeinterval target:self selector:@selector(updatplayer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
here i need this timeinterval value

can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your timer as:

```
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(updatplayer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)updatplayer {
     long currentPlaybackTime = moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime;
     playSlider.value = currentPlaybackTime / moviePlayer.duration;
}
```

Comment: hi here i am not using moviePlayer we are using AVAudio player and the slider bar is uiimages we are changing that image x values to move it

Comment: - (void)updatplayer {
     long currentPlaybackTime = audioPlayer.currentTime;
     playSlider.center.x = (currentPlaybackTime*progressImage.frame.size.width) / audioPlayer.duration;                                             
}                                                                 where progressImage is the highlight area of played audio and playSlider is pointer in the ProgressImage which will move along x axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your time interval as a class property and access it from there. In example:

```
@interface YourClass ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval myTimeInterval);

@end

@implementation YourClass

- (void)methodWithYourTimerInIt {

    // ... Do stuff
    self.myTimeInterval = 6.0;
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.myTimeInterval target:self selector:@selector(updatePlayer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updatePlayer {

    NSLog(@"My time interval is: %f", self.myTimeInterval);
}

@end
```

Comment: i Want this value calculation  self.myTimeInterval = 6.0; please can u help me dynamicaly

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. You can set that property to whatever calculation you do.